# Changing Array's Value Outside Doesn't Effect Value In Array

Tags: swift2

I want to change blue value with red code, but it doesn't effect, how to achieve this without making green code?

[image]

```
import Cocoa

var test0 = false
var test1 = false
var test2 = false
var test3 = true

var array = [test0, test1, test2, test3]

test0 = true

array

array[0] = true

array
```

Comment: Hello. It's ok to post a screenshot but you also have to post the code as text in your question. You can use the [edit] button. Thank you.

Comment: ok fixed my question, possible duplicate solution as setting NSMutableArray didn't work for this

Comment: We like Swift because it´s value semantic. We like functional programming because it's no side effect behavior. Why did you choose Swift for your project, if you don't like this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

This is just worked, seems we need some pointer in array not a property

```
class TestEntity: NSObject {
   var isDone: Bool!
   init(status: Bool) {
    isDone = status
   }
}


var test4 : TestEntity = TestEntity(status: false)
var test5 : TestEntity = TestEntity(status: false)
var test6 : TestEntity = TestEntity(status: false)
var test7 : TestEntity = TestEntity(status: true)

var array2: NSMutableArray = [test4, test5, test6, test7]

test4.isDone = true

array2
```

[image]